# Trigger Azure pipeline with params from Microsoft teams

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to trigger Azure pipeline from Microsoft teams?

I am able to subscribe updates from azure pipeline in team

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate like what parameters you have to add here?

Comment: Let's say, I am using azure pipeline to run a python script and that script requires a string argument. I need trigger Azure build from teams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to subscribe updates from azure pipeline in team

From your question, it seems you are using Azure Pipelines App in Teams. I think you want to know whether this app can trigger azure pipeline in DevOps?

**If so, the answer is NO.**

See the official document:

[Use Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops)

[Available commands in Azure Pipelines app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops#use-commands-in-azure-pipelines-app)

[image]

As you can see, no commands in this app can achieve your requirement.

And, Azure pipeline app was started from 2019, the original intention of the design is mainly for monitor the pipelines:

[Azure Pipelines app on Microsoft Teams enables you to monitor the events for your pipelines.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/new-azure-pipelines-app-for-microsoft-teams/ba-p/645225)

Official app of azure pipeline doesn't support your requirements. If you want trigger your pipeline from Teams, I think you need to design your own app, the related technology should be this:

[Webhooks and connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors)

The trigger type will be 'Manually trigger' in this situation.